# Newtonsoft JSON is not deserializing the nested object in my json file

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I have a JSON file that I am trying to deserialize.

```
[
  {
    "colorData": [
      255,
      255,
      255
    ],
    "Neighbours": [
      {
        "Item1": 0,
        "Item2": [
          {
            "colorData": [
              255,
              255,
              255
            ],
            "numberOfExamples": 188
          },
          {
            "colorData": [
              255,
              24,
              0
            ],
            "numberOfExamples": 15
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Item1": 1,
        "Item2": [
          {
            "colorData": [
              255,
              255,
              255
            ],
            "numberOfExamples": 188
          },
          {
            "colorData": [
              255,
              24,
              0
            ],
            "numberOfExamples": 15
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Item1": 2,
        "Item2": [
          {
            "colorData": [
              255,
              255,
              255
            ],
            "numberOfExamples": 188
          },
          {
            "colorData": [
              255,
              24,
              0
            ],
            "numberOfExamples": 15
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Item1": 3,
        "Item2": [
          {
            "colorData": [
              255,
              255,
              255
            ],
            "numberOfExamples": 188
          },
          {
            "colorData": [
              255,
              24,
              0
            ],
            "numberOfExamples": 15
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

This is the object I'm trying to deserialize it into:

```
public partial class ImageBrainData_Reader
{
    public int[] colorData { get; set; }
    public List<Neighbour_Reader> neighbours { get; set; }
}

public partial class Neighbour_Reader
{
    public int direction { get; set; }
    public List<NeighbourData_Reader> neighbourData_Reader { get; set; }     
}

public partial class NeighbourData_Reader
{
    public int[] colorData { get; set; }
    public int numberOfExamples { get; set; }
}
```

And this is what I'm doing to load it from a file:

```
 List<ImageBrainData_Reader> dataRead = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ImageBrainData_Reader>>(File.ReadAllText(fileName + ".json"));
```

The first part (`colorData`) gets brought in and the correct amount of nested `Neighbours`, but none of the data from them (`Item1` and `Item2`) are being read. Instead of getting the data, they are defaulting to their default values (0 and null, respectively).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Json.Net doesn't have any way to know that `Item1` maps to `direction` and `Item2` maps to `neighbourData_Reader` unless you tell it.  You either need to add some `[JsonProperty]` attributes as shown below, or rename your properties to match the JSON.

```
public partial class Neighbour_Reader
{
    [JsonProperty("Item1")]
    public int direction { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Item2")]
    public List<NeighbourData_Reader> neighbourData_Reader { get; set; }
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ajE0HD

Comment: OMG, I can't believe that was what was causing the issue. I copy pasted the object that it was read into from my classes which the data was written from which was using Tuple (thus the item1 and item2). Thank you so much! I've been stuck on this all day!

Comment: Glad I could help!